# What do you call a quote collector?

Tags: single-word-requests

EDIT: As Chris Taylor made note of, there are multiple types of quotes. I mean quotes as in phrases written/spoken by someone (not insurance quotes, etc.).

Is there a single word that describes someone who collects quotes? I've seen both *quotologist* and *quotographer* used, but I'm not sure if either of those is "acceptable" in any serious circle.

Thoughts?

Comment: A journalist? ;^)

Comment: A paræmiographer collects proverbs...it's a start, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the word is

> Quodophile

but I can't find it in any dictionary. It seems to be used quite a lot though. For example, there is: @Quodophile on Twitter or http://quodophile.tumblr.com/ who collect quotes.

This is based on if you mean quotes to be phrases by someone. If you mean quotes as in "insurance quotes", then the word might be 'client/customer' or 'potential client/customer'.

Comment: _Quodophile_ seems more like a word to describe someone who loves quotes, not necessarily collects them. I'm sure there's major crossover between the two, but, just as with calling a coin collector a "numismatist", I think there's an importance to differentiate the two. Nonetheless, I'm grateful for the new word to describe myself!

Comment: Oh, and yes -- I mean quotes as in phrases by someone.

Comment: I think the main issue you'll have in finding a word here is that quotes are unlike stamps and coins, in that you can't actually "own" a quote. Quotes are intangible, so there will be no precise quote equivalent to a philatelist or a numismatist.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer the last half of an answer. A 'quotationist' is a "person who habitually uses quotations; (Literary Criticism) a writer whose work makes reference or allusion to the past" ([*OED*](https://oed.com/)). *OED* provides attestation of the senses ranging from 1644 (Milton) to 1985 (Hartman). A quick search at HathiTrust and elsewhere online turns up uses of 'quotationist' in the sense of a "person who habitually uses quotations" well into the 21st century.

The problem with 'quotationist' as an answer to this question ("What do you call a quote collector?"), and the reason I call it the last half of an answer, is that while anybody who habitually uses quotations must certainly have collected the quotes, a person who collects quotes does not necessarily use them, and so is not necessarily a quotationist in the historical sense.

For my part, I would not hesitate, if I thought I would be adequately understood, to call a mere collector of quotes a quotationist.

Answer (score 0):

The single word you are looking for is the term COMMONPLACE. The Commonplace Book was a compilation of quotes, observations, proverbs and other miscellany gathered by an individual as an aid to memory and learning. The famous philosopher, John Locke, considered them so important to wisdom that he wrote a guidebook entitled, "A New Method of Making Common-Place-Books" to help others with this task. The Commonplace Book emerged during the Renaissance and became a popular past time during the Victorian era.  ~. rd armstrong

Comment: Doesn't commonplace in this context describe the book and not the person creating it? I think the OP wants a word to describe the person doing the collecting.

Answer (score 0):

What about "quote-addict"? (not a single word... OK... but almost)